# Two Web Jobs Appear to be locking each other

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobs, azure-web-app-service

Could someone help me to discover what is going on with our App Services. We have two App services connected to two Blob Storage containers that are triggered when an item is placed on the container they are listening to.

```
    App One         App two       (under the same subscription)
       |               |
    WebJobs(9)     WebJobs(9)
       |               |
 Container one   Container Two    (under the same storage account)
```

This represents environments so App One is our dev environment and App two is our Test environment. Each item that is placed into each of the containers triggers a webjob in its App Service. there is also an archive container under the storage account for each App Service where a copy of the Blob is archived.

the situation we are in is that we seem to be unable to run both WebJobs at the same time (1 of the 9 in each). We can only get a trigger activating in one WebJob when the WebJob in the other App Service is stopped. They appear to be locking each other out but I was under the impression that the structure we have would keep all of that separate and the locks would not interfere with each other. the info I can find is that reading a Blob gets a lock on the Blob and updating a Blob gets a lock on the container. If that is correct then why do they appear to be locking each other out.

Any advice on what may be causing this or how to move forward in trouble shooting it wil be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be related to your WebJobs functions logic. If WebJobs access the same resource at the same time, the WebJobs will influence each other. And then it will cause the problem. Please have a look at the [conflict section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/background-jobs#conflicts).

Comment: I thought that the point here is that they are not accessing the same resource. Its all within the same storage account but the containers are separate for each so the resources in the containers are separate.